# How do I get my validation to work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this code to validate the length of the text.

```
function validate() {
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
if(firstname.length > 15) {alert("The first name cannot be this long.");
return false;}
}
```

and here is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title> Contact Page </title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "contactform.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Contact Page </h1>

<form id = "contactform" action = "">
<p> Name: </p>
<label>
<input name = "firstname" type = "text" id = "firstname" onclick =                                
"validate()"/>
</label>
<p>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear" />
</p>
</form>     
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "contactform.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: What's not working - any error?

Comment: _The onclick event occurs when the user clicks on an element._ Looks to me like your `validate()` is being called when you click into the input element

Comment: When you attach the `validate` function to the `onclick` attribute, it is triggering the function when the user first clicks into the input box, which should be empty.

Comment: I tried using onsubmit but it didn't work

Comment: @vabii nothing happens when i submit the form. i tried onsubmit as well

Comment: @rajzaveri5, the first 2 answers below are working for me. Is you path for javascript file correct? You can try alert('hello') before your JS function and reload the page, see if alerts. You can also open developer tools and then try to run the code and see if it shows any error on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `pattern` attribute with following regex:

**`.{1,15}`**, which sets a limit of maximum 15 characters inside the input.

**Note**: Remember to use the `required` attribute aswell, to prevent user submitting the form if the input is **empty**.

```html
<form id="contactform" action="">
  <p> Name: </p>
  <label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" pattern=".{1,15}" required/>
</label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return true;` outside your `if` condition on your `validate()` function, then use it on form's `onsubmit` event:

```js
function validate() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
  if(firstname.length > 15) {
    alert("The first name cannot be this long.");
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactform" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <p> Name: </p>
  <label>
    <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" />
  </label>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
  </p>
</form>
```

You can also add more validations in that function.